# Is there a way to use generics in typescript to work with Function.apply?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a wrapper of sorts that takes a function reference. Best way to explain was to create a small snippet:

```
// Function to wrap
function testFn(a: string, b: string) {
    return `${a} ${b}`
}

// Some sort of generic wrapper
function wrapper<T extends Function>(fn: T) {

    const execute = (args: ThisParameterType<T>) => {
        fn.apply(args)
    }

    // This wrapper returns this method to be called later
    return { 
        execute
    }
}

const wrappedFn = wrapper(testFn)

//.... some time/place later

wrappedFn.execute('Hello', 'World')
```

When calling `wrappedFn.execute()` later is it possible to get the argument types from the `testFn`

Tried using `ThisParameterType` but it doesn't seem to be the right tool for the job or I don't know how to use it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, `ThisParameterType` isn't what you're looking for (or at least, not primarily), you're looking for [`Parameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype), which gives you a tuple of the function's parameter types. To use it, we also need to change the constraint on `T` (just FYI, `Function` generally isn't useful). Also, the first argument to `apply` is the value to use as `this`, not the arguments to use; that's the second argument. So:

```
// Function to wrap
function testFn(a: string, b: string) {
    return `${a} ${b}`;
}

// Some sort of generic wrapper
function wrapper<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(fn: T) {
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    const execute = (...args: Parameters<T>) => {
//                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        fn.apply(null, args);
//               ^^^^^^
    };

    // This wrapper returns this method to be called later
    return {
        execute,
    };
}

const wrappedFn = wrapper(testFn);

//.... some time/place later

wrappedFn.execute("Hello", "World");
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEDEFcDsGMBcCWB7ap7NAdwE4EMAHAKADMYEU14BTAZ3nGgAo8AuUenRaAcwBpQAI3aduPAJSgA3kVBzQOavEg40AAwAkUvAF9QWwTrUBuIjqJEQoAMrIAttQ7Ic8UMhKge1aNS6xs+AQEvqTkSKgBhME4ADwAKqDUAB400AAmtKBMAHS5eDg8tOx40ACeANoAupIAvAB8oCWldUwk0OxxkjJW8r19-f0AesMjo2Pjw7LysKj0iUnUsJA0oDVZudn5hewACvl4DjQ4tPF1tQ3dYAPX8hN3E1P9bZtBADalTNCQr68CW7TiUw9G69caPUA6UzgqxxAAWiEyuCivgUShU0Ey8HhmUOsOQaXQmEEjlgeB+1AJrzwR3BimUqmk4N6yUWy2ofHBkLMFhmGNcSKCFMYq0igpwTBo9EYgIsIA22ScDnQiAcwAIVNgjipNKIAuCaUY2RZSxoTAARAAJag-ZBmgRmgDqzleaTNMqAA)

---

It's relatively unusual (but perfectly fine) to use `apply` these days. The more modern way is to use argument spread notation: `fn(...args);`

---

You might also consider supporting the return type of the function (via [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype)), and returning whatever it returns:

```
const execute = (...args: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T> => {
//                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return fn(...args);
//  ^^^^^^
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEDEFcDsGMBcCWB7ap7NAdwE4EMAHAKADMYEU14BTAZ3nGgAo8AuUenRaAcwBpQAI3aduPAJSgA3kVBzQOavEg40AAwAkUvAF9QWwTrUBuIjqJEQoAMrIAttQ7Ic8UMhKge1aNS6xs+AQEvqTkSKgBhME4ADwAKqDUAB400AAmtKBMAHS5eDg8tOx40ACeANoAupIAvAB8oCWldUwk0OxxkjJW8r19-f0AesMjo2Pjw7LysKj0iUnUsJA0oDVZudn5hewACvl4DjQ4tPF14uwASkoq0HGlwaerDTK9PQPvH59yEz9T-YrKVSgNo5PIFWjiUyvMCgcZ-UA6UzwqxxAAWiEyuCivgU11UmXg6Myh1RyDS6EwgkcsDwABtadRybS8Ed4QCbtJ4b1kotltQ+PDEWYLDNoHMsUFGYxVpFJTgmDR6IxIRYQBtsk4HOhEA5gARmbBHMzWUQJcE0oxsjyljQmAAiAAS1HpyDtAjtAHVnLS0naVUA)

---

FWIW, you'd use `ThisParameterType` if you needed to support functions that require a specific `this` value. (And you'd probably go back to using `apply` in that case.) But you don't seem to need to do that.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and explanation! Exactly what I was trying to do. I am still learning Typescript so the FWIW sections are great.